# App engine index.search(query) always returns zero results

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api, google-app-engine-python

I created search documents in index 'search-user'. Later when I do a global search query on the index, I always get zero results both in development and production. Here is my query code,

```
index = search.Index(name=user_index)
try:
    results = index.search(query)
    for user_document in results:
        print 'doc'
except search.Error:
    logging.exception('Search failed')
```

'doc' never gets printed.

Comment: What is your query? Have you opened the appengine console checked the index manually?

Comment: @Jesse It is a global search, so query is just the search string. I checked in admin, the values are there. When I run the query in admin console also, I don't get the results.

Comment: Maybe your app uses a namespace different from the namespace where the index is.
Try something like this instead of the search:
`doc_ids = [doc.doc_id for doc in search.Index(name=user_index).get_range(ids_only=True)]` and then
`print len(doc_ids)`
If you get documents back, the cause for the empty search results might be an error with your query.